# Program won't return highest or smallest values using math methods

Tags: javascript, math, methods, while-loop

help im trying to get my code to alert The hisgest number input and lowest why isn't mine doing that?

```
let price;
let items = 0; 
let sum=0;
let big = 0 ;
let small = 0;

price = Number(prompt("Please enter the price of the Item you choose to buy or enter -1 to stop: "));

while (price != -1){

    sum=sum+price;
    items++;
    avg = sum/items;
    Big = Math.max(Number(price));
    small = Math.min(Number(price));
    price = Number(prompt("Please enter the price of the Item you choose to buy or enter -1 to stop: "));
    
   
}

alert("You have purchased "+items+" items!");
alert("the sum of items you purchased is: $"+sum);
alert("the Averege of the items is: " + avg);
alert("The highest item price purchased was: "+ Big);
alert("The lowest item price was: "+ small);
```

Comment: You have to give `Math.max()` multiple arguments. It returns the highest of all the arguments.

Comment: If you just give it one argument, it just returns that, since there's nothing else to compare to.

Comment: Why do you write `Number(price)`? You converted it to a number when you assigned the variable, you don't have to convert it again.

Comment: How would i get the highest input return

Comment: Compare the current input to `Big`. If it's higher, replace `Big`.

Comment: can you explain that how would i make "big" return highest value?

Comment: `if (price > Big) Big = price`

Comment: Where would i even include that though outside or in my while loop I'm not the most experienced. lol your kind of explaining this like I've been doing this for a while which I haven't

Comment: You don't seem to be thinking about it. It replaces `Big = Math.max(price)`

Answer (score 0):

Using function isNumeric to check for `valid numbers`.
Using  array  named `itemsPurchased`to store all the valid purchases `not including empty string, negative numbers`.

Using `template strings, destructuring assignment,  Array.prototype.reduce() , Math.max(),  spread operator , Math.min() and Array.prototype.length` to get the desired result.

```js
function isValidNumber(str) {
  if (typeof str != "string") return false;
  return (
    !isNaN(str) && 
    !isNaN(parseFloat(str))
  );
}

function purchaseCalculation() {
  let price,
    expensive,
    cheap,
    itemsNumber,
    average,
    total,
    itemsPurchased = [];

  price = prompt(
    "Please enter the price of the Item you choose to buy or enter -1 to stop: "
  );
  while (price !== "-1") {
    if (isValidNumber(price) && Number(price) >= 0) {
      itemsPurchased.push(Number(price));
    }
    price = prompt(
      "Please enter the price of the Item you choose to buy or enter -1 to stop: "
    );
  }

  expensive = itemsPurchased.length === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(...itemsPurchased);
  cheap = itemsPurchased.length === 0 ? 0 : Math.min(...itemsPurchased);
  total = itemsPurchased.reduce((total, item) => total + item, 0);
  itemsNumber = itemsPurchased.length;
  average = total === 0 ? 0 : total / itemsNumber;

  return [cheap, expensive, total, itemsNumber, average];
}


const [cheap, expensive, total, itemsNumber, average] = purchaseCalculation();
alert(
  `You have purchased ${itemsNumber} ${itemsNumber > 1 ? "items" : "item"}!`
);
alert(
  `The sum of ${
    itemsNumber > 1 ? "items" : "item"
  } you purchased was: $${total}`
);
alert(
  `The average of the ${itemsNumber > 1 ? "items" : "item"} was: ${average}`
);
alert(`The highest item price purchased was: ${expensive}`);
alert(`The lowest item price was: ${cheap}`);
```